# Printing difference of offsetTop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

This is the code
I am not getting the difference of offsetTop.. Where i am doing mistake?? 
But if i put individual i and n values, output comes..

```
<html>
<body>

    <div class="names" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 53px;">
        <span id="f12" style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: baseline; color: red;">Joe</span>
    </div>
    <div class="names" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 64px;">
        <span id="f12" style="font-size: 12px; vertical- align: baseline; color: blue;">John</span>
    </div>
    <div class="names" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 76px;">
        <span id="f12" style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: baseline; color: red;">Jony</span>
    </div>
    <div class="names" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 89px;">
        <span id="f12" style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: baseline; color: blue;">Jonson</span>
    </div>
    <div class="names" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 100px;">
        <span id="f12" style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: baseline; color: red;">Juni</span>
    </div>
    <div class="names" style="position: absolute; left: 13px; top: 113px;">
        <span id="f12" style="font-size: 12px; vertical-align: baseline; color: blue;">Juno</span>
    </div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            var i = 0;
            var n;
            var gap = "";
            do {
                n = i + 1;
                gap += x[n].offsetTop - x[i].offsetTop + " ";
                i++;
            }
            while (i < x.length);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gap;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the difference of offsetTop.. Where i am doing mistake?? 
But if i put individual i and n values, output comes..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, https://jsfiddle.net/7yhp7a8g/ changed the code a bit

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  var i=0;
  var n = i;
  var gap = " ";
  do{
      i++;
      gap += x[i].offsetTop - x[n].offsetTop + " ";
      n=i;
  }
  while (i < x.length - 1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = gap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `n = i + 1`, you will end up with an index bigger than your collection's length. Remove that statement and it will work:

```
do{
    n = i;
    gap += x[n].offsetTop-x[i].offsetTop + " ";
    i++;
}
```

Comment: All values r coming 0..  Where u can see in the data that first value is 11(64-53), second value is 12(76-64), and so on... so by making n = i will not serve purpose..